# Define relation at model without migration which adds FK constraint?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, relation, activemodel

When we define relationships between two tables at Rails, we usually do like

1. Run command for generate migration file like `rails g migration AddUserToTask user:belongs_to`
2. And add line at model to define type of relationships like `has_many :users`

Then, how about just do step2, which is just add line for define relationships at model?

Does it work?

If so, why we usually do step1?

=====

And, what happen in the case like below?

1. Just creating column which is necessary for association(like user_id). And this column doesn't have FK constraint at sql level.
2. And add line at model to define type of relationships like `has_many :users` with column name which is made at step 1

That means, there is the column needed for association, but it doesn't have FK constraint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you can set a relation just by creating the FK on the table (the migration), and manage all the query stuff by hand (set `user_id`, retrieve by `user_id`, etc.).

When, after run the migration, you set the association on the models you rely on Rails to do all that hard work.

So, you can live without the model association, but not without the table FK.

Comment: Thanks for your replay.

How about case like below?

① I have the columns which is necessary for the association like use_id, but without FK constraint(at sql level).
② Then, at rails model, I define the association with column name.

Does it works correctly?

Comment: From a Rails point of view, yes it does. It used to be that way some time ago. Now it is considered a bad practice.

Comment: Hmmm, I got it.
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

The first step creates the relationship on the database, so it's adding the column `user_id` in the `tasks` table.

After this, when you save a task, e.g.

```
> task = Task.first
> task.user = User.first
> task.save
```

It's saving the user's id in the `user_id` field in the `tasks` table.

Without this column, the association `has_many` will not work, because there's no link between a User and a Task in the database.

Also, in your example migration, the correct association should be to add `has_many :tasks` to the `User` model, and `belongs_to :user` in the `Task` model.